# Where to find the meta keys for WooCommerce user profile fields?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, gravity-forms-plugin, user-profile

I want to add user data from a user registration form I am adding to my wordpress site via Gravity Forms. I want the address information in my form to be added to the Shipping Address fields that Woocommerce adds to my user profile. This should be simple enough but I need to have the meta keys for these fields. Can anyone tell me where to find these meta keys?

When I look at the code in my user profile it shows the field for shipping address has an id and name of "shipping_address_1". Is this also the meta key?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The field 'name' in the HTML input in the user profile is the meta key.  (Note: depending on how a given developer handles creating their inputs, this may or may not be the case; but in the case of WooCommerce it is.)

There is a list of meta keys for WooCommerce's checkout fields on this page:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/